# Push Checked Value into An Array

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to push checked values into an array in order to store user input. I've created a loop to evaluate which checkBoxes have been selected using `checked` (seen in the "if" statement). The for loop recognizes the inputs however isn't pushing the checked values into the array as requested to in the "if" statement condition.

```js
const checkBox = document.getElementsByName('type');

for (let i = 0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
    arr = [];
    if (checkBox[i].checked) {
        arr.push(checkBox[i])
    }
}

console.log(arr)
```

```html
 <div class="items">
        <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="1"  />Item 1
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="2" />Item 2
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" />Item 3
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" />Item 4
    </div>
```

Comment: you're initializing your array each iteration. move that outside of the loop

Comment: @Kinglish I've shifted the arr = [] into a global scope (outside the for of loop). When I console.log(arr) it comes up as an empty arr

Comment: The one in your question is inside the for loop tho.

Comment: I think the OP may be expecting the console to update as a box is checked but there is no listener or handler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're initializing your array each iteration. move that outside of the loop

Though, here's a shortcut - you can access just the checked checkboxes with the selector `input[type=checkbox]:checked`- in which case use `document.querySelectorAll`

```
arr = [];
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').forEach(el => arr.push(el.value));
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName('input[type=checkbox]:checked') is not reading the input items. Also, are you using the forEach loop because the inputs are stored inside of a node list?

Comment: I updated my answer. I use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ES6 method that I use frequently:

```js
const arr = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=type]'))
  .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
  .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="1" />Item 1
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="2" checked/>Item 2
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" />Item 3
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" checked/>Item 4
</div>
```